Can you leave browsershot chrome open for multiple pdf document generations?
At the moment I'm generating a pdf from HTML, which is taking about 4s each time, which in its self is too long.
I have 40k of these pdfs to generate.
Is there a way that I can essentially skip the creation of the browser for each pdf.
So have it open, create and save the pdf, and then move to the next pdf before finally closing the browser?

Can you just use plain Puppeteer? I'm not familiar with browsershot, but depending on what specific functionality you need from it, I suspect Puppeteer can do it just fine, and it's only a one-liner to take a screenshot in Puppeteer and a few extra lines to create and manage the browser/page.

unfortunately, i can't just use plain puppeteer.  essentially I am creating 40k of the same pdf, but it is customized for each person with their name and details (which happens to be a header on each page, and some copy within the pdf)

I'm working on a commercial product based on Puppeter and we experienced the same issue. We decided to cache the browser instance per user session and generate each report in a separate browser tab. Opening the browser can take a few seconds while opening a tab is usually around 100ms.

that is actually not a bad idea, thanks Marko
